# What are the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{i}{(x+e^{ix})}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The variable x in this case is real...not complex.  At first blush $\frac{i}{(x+e^{ix})}$ wouldn't seem to have any real part.  It looks like i divided by some stuff.  However, plotting this with Mathematica shows there is definitely a real part.  How does one go about finding the real and imaginary parts of this function?

Comment: Write $e^{ix}$ as $\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ and then use the usual technique for realifying the denominator (multiplying and dividing by the conjugate).

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac { i }{ (x+e^{ ix }) } =\frac { i }{ x+\cos { x+i\sin { x }  }  } =\frac { i\left( x+\cos { x-i\sin { x }  }  \right)  }{ \left( x+\cos { x+i\sin { x }  }  \right) \left( x+\cos { x-i\sin { x }  }  \right)  } =\\ =\frac { \sin { x }  }{ \left( x+\cos { x }  \right) ^{ 2 }+\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  } +i\frac { x+\cos { x }  }{ \left( x+\cos { x }  \right) ^{ 2 }+\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  } $$